# Build a project from another project C# (net 5.0)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I was trying to build console application from Windows Form (net 5.0).

```
var globalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Configuration", "Debug" }, { "Platform", "AnyCPU" } };
        
var buildParameters = new BuildParameters(new ProjectCollection()) { Loggers = new List<ILogger> { new ConsoleLogger() } };
                    
var buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(@"C:\Users\User\source\repos\BuildFromWinForm\BuildFromWinForm\BuildFromWinForm.csproj", globalProperty, "Current", new[] { "Build" },null );
        
BuildResult buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(buildParameters, buildRequest);
```

csproj WinForm:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build" Version="16.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

csproj console app:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework" Version="16.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Due to errors I had to set Environment variable - MSBuildSDKsPath, also I had to change Sdk.props, replacing

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="'$(AlternateCommonProps)' == ''"/>
```

with

```
<Import Project="C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.202/Current/Microsoft.Common.props" />
```

Now I have exception

```
The expression "[MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkIdentifier(net5.0)" cannot be evaluated. MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: A required NuGet assembly was not found. Expected Path: C:\Users\User\source\repos\BuildFromWinForm\ConsoleBuilder\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows
```

Comment: Why not just programmatically run console command `dotnet build ...` ?

Comment: @GuruStron Probably I will do it with command, thanks for help. But I am interesting why NuGet assembly is missing.

Comment: msbuild with command also doesn't work on net 5.0

Comment: What command have you used, what errors are you getting?

Comment: I was using msbuild C:\Users\User\source\repos\x\x\x.csproj /p:Platform="AnyCPU". In cmd build was succeeded, but dlls 'date modified' was same. But I added  /t:Clean,Build and now it works fine. Thank you for help

Comment: Glad if my comments helped. =)